# phpseclib NET_SSH2 hangs when server is down or slow

Tags: php, ssh, timeout, freeze, phpseclib

I am using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) library to perform SSH. Whenever the server is down or very slow, the script stucks at this point.

```
<?php
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($bind_ip, $port, 10);
?>
```

When I use Putty, it does not prompt me to login..

How can I timeout or force continue?

Any suggestions?

Thank you!!

Comment: This has been fixed in the recent version.